# error: (1347) can't find 0x422 words (0x422 withtotal) for psect "maintext_split_2" in class "CODE" (largest unused contiguous range 0x3AD)

Tags: c, pic, mplab

im on mplab, using C with PIC16F18326 and am getting the following error when i try to compile:

> :0:: error: (1347) can't find 0x422 words (0x422 withtotal) for psect "maintext_split_2" in class "CODE" (largest unused contiguous range 0x3AD)

I know that this is a memory error, something that should be stored in `maintext_split_2` now doesnt fit but i dont know what part of the code it is. Ive had this before but instead of main text it usually says something like "`text5`". When checking the map file for `text5` it'll give me a list of functions that are sotred there so i can trim or remove them and that will sort it.

This error does not give me any information as to what is stored there, ive cut my main in half, trimmed a few functions but still get the same error.

Comment: Turns out it is that my main code is too long, i didnt think this was possible...i still have 16% space left on the chip. Ill try trimming it down again

Comment: Looks like you are running out of memory. Maybe this helps:https://www.microchip.com/forums/m1035952.aspx

Comment: Maybe large tables or subroutines?